# Software to manage a very long waiting list

Tags: email, crm, marketing

an organization has a *very* long waiting list for becoming a member. You sign up, then after *four or five years* they call you back. It can be done by hand, but it's tedious, because 500 people sign up, but then after 5 years only 10 of them actually want to join, and it's a massive waste of time to call all of those people.

So I am searching for a software that:

- takes info in a form (name, DOB, email, sex)
- manually or automatically sends a yearly email like "are you still interested? Click here to unsubscribe"
- automatically purges all the invalid emails (hard bounces) and unsubscribes
- has an easy way to segment the signups, like "show all the people born in the 1988", or "show all the men born in 1976"

Basically this can be done with any email marketing software, except a detail: **I need to have duplicate email addresses**.

If a whole family wants to sign up, **they will use the same email for four different entries** (mom, dad, kid1, kid2), and most email marketing solutions don't allow this.

So... basically this could also be formulated in "there's a mailchimp alternative (better if self hosted) that allows duplicate email addresses in the list?"

Comment: Does this mean the software will not be used for managing the actual membership like payments, etc? i.e. you want it just for the waiting list/emails?

Comment: @ZZ yes, just for waiting list / emails

Comment: I think in mautic [www.mautic.org] or phplist [www.phplist.org], you can manually create contacts with same email. But you will need to verify yourself - search their forums first. The other solutions I can think of may be overkill since you only want for emails.

Comment: Nice, looks like mautic can set the email to not be the unique user identifier, allowing duplicates. I'll try this solution, thanks!

Comment: Great. I have added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the suggestions from above as solutions:
From my recollection, I think in [Mautic](http://www.mautic.org) or [Phplist](http://www.phplist.org), you can manually create contacts with same email. Please search their old forums to see a couple of ways to get around this. But you will need to verify yourself that this meets your full requirements.

The other solutions I can think of may be overkill since you only want to use to send emails i.e. no need for running membership, payments, etc.